# Bigquery request data from 2 arrays

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the following BigQuery Export data scheme https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089

And want to export hits data with extra 2 fields from custom dimensions (array fields) on plain SQL it would be something like this:

`select visitId,visitStartTime,customDimensions.value, hits.SOME_HIT_INFO,
hits.customDimensions.value
from session_data 
left join hits
left join customDimensions where customDimensions.index=100
left join hits.customDimensions where hits.customDimensions.index=200`

How it will look on BigQuery query syntax ?

UPD:

for example I have the folowing data:

```
{
'visitId' : 1
'visitStartTime' : ...,
....
'hits' : [
  {
    'refferer: 'REF1'
    ....
    'customDimensions' : [
       {'index':200,'value':'HITVALUE200'},
       {'index':202,'value':'HITVALUE202'},
    ]
  }
],
'customDimensions' : [
   {'index':100,'value':'VALUE100'},
   {'index':102,'value':'VALUE102'},
]
}
```

I want to receive something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| visitId | hits.refferer | hits_cd_INDEX_201 | cd_INDEX_101 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1       | REF1          | HITVALUE201       | HITVALUE101  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```

Comment: not clear what exactly you need! please provide more info. like what is expected result?

Comment: and what the logic behind this? btw. your expected output does not match with the example you provided!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: I want to extract 2 special values (based in index ) from array fields acording their index. General bigquery syntax does not allow it,  thats why I have written this pseudo SQL request.

Comment: i see  - just wanted to double check - hits field is an array - so for the same visitId you will get potentially multiple refferers and respective hitvalues  - correct?

Comment: Yes - i want to receive array of "hits" with 2 extra values: value of hitCusomDimension with index 200 , and value of customDimension with index 100 for each hit.

Comment: makes total sense - typing the answer now :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT visitId,   
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT refferer, 
      (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(hit.customDimensions) dim WHERE index = 200) cd_index_200 
    FROM UNNEST(hits) hit
    ) hits,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) dim WHERE index = 100) cd_index_100
FROM `project.dataset.session_data`
```